# scipy.io.loadmat: Matlab logical array to Numpy bool array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'd like to successfully read a Matlab `logical` array as a Numpy `bool` array using Python.

But if I save a logical array in Matlab,

```
l = rand(1,10) > 0.5; save -v6 file.mat l
```

and try to load it into Python,

```
d = scipy.io.loadmat('file.mat')
l = d['l']
```

then the datatype of `l` is `uint8`

Also, if I try using the `mat_dtype=True` option, then the datatype of `l` becomes `float64`.

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried both version 6 and version 7 MAT files, which are both supported by `scipy.io.loadmat`.

Comment: probably not, but where is the problem? A boolean array is just a uint8/int8 with a different type pretty much, so just cast it in numpy, numpy won't even make a copy.

Comment: @Sebastian, I'm writing something for others who use both Matlab and Python, and it matters because integers and logicals are treated differently when it comes to indexing arrays. Users would have to be conscientious of arbitrary type switching when saving/loading MAT files. I'll live - I guess it's just a scipy bug.

Comment: In Matlab R2020b, an empty array [] is typed as double, by default. I was using `bool_array = []` to concatenate boolean arrays of different sizes iteratively in a for loop, but I didn't realize that the final array was typed as double. That was my problem. It was on Matlab, not on Scipy.